# cilk.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, g++, cilk

I compile in Ubuntu 20.04 with gcc 7.5.0 and g++ 7.5.0(supporting cilk plus), but the error says that 'cilk/cilk.h: No such file or directory'[the error is shown in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05gzV.png)

Anybody could help me with the situation? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I recently stumbled upon the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler still doesn't support cilkplus, just install it via apt-get install:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libcilkrts5
```

there you go,

**UPDATE**: Cilk is not supported with the gcc package on ubuntu 20.04,
to have cilk on ubuntu 20.04 you have to install `gcc version < 7` , by the following instruction it's possible to install gcc-6 g++6 on ubuntu 20.04,

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
add "deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe" to file
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install gcc-6 g++-6 -y
```

check by `gcc -v` if you have downgraded correctly the gcc version Then the cilk extension should work.